# adding layer to a plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot

Taking some generic data

```
A <- c(1997,2000,2000,1998,2000,1997,1997,1997)
B <- c(0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0)
df <- data.frame(A,B)

counts <- t(table(A,B))
frac <- counts[1,]/(counts[2,]+counts[1,])


C <- c(1998,2001,2000,1995,2000,1996,1998,1999)
D <- c(1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1)
df2 <- data.frame(C,D)

counts2 <- t(table(C,D))
frac2 <- counts2[1,]/(counts2[2,]+counts2[1,])
```

If we then want to create a scatterplot for the two datasets on the one scale

We can:

```
plot(frac, pch=22)
points(frac2, pch=19)
```

But we see we have two problems

- first we want to put our year values (which appear as `df$A` and `df$C`) along the x axis
- We want the x axis to automatically adjust the scale when the second data is added.

A solution using `ggplot2` or base R would be desired

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ggplot` will do the scaling for you.  You can convert the `frac`s to `data.frame` and to use with `ggplot`

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data.frame(y=frac, x=names(frac)), aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point(col="salmon") +
  geom_point(data=data.frame(y=frac2, x=names(frac2)), aes(x, y), col="steelblue") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]